# How to get list values ​that are in rows from a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a data frame of messages from a social network. In this date frame, I created a new column without stop words with the use of a lambda function. As a result in this new column, the values ​​are inserted within a list. What I need is to get the values ​​within this list.

What I have:

```
raw_data = {'CLASS':['1', '2', '3', '1', '2','3','2'],
        'MESSAGES': [['mama', 'said', 'home'],['dad', 'said', 'soccer', 'reality'], ['matrix', 'you'],
                     ['run', 'neo', 'free'], ['what', 'doing'], ['begnning', 'believe'],
                    ['choice', 'let', 'you', 'free', 'mind']]}
dfRaw = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['CLASS','MESSAGES'])
```

What I need:

```
clean_data = {'CLASS':['1', '2', '3', '1', '2','3','2'],
            'MESSAGES':['mama, said, home', 'dad, said, soccer, reality', 'matrix, you', 'run, neo, free', 'what, doing','begnning, believe','choice, let, you, free, mind']}
dfEndResult = pd.DataFrame(clean_data, columns = ['CLASS','MESSAGES'])
```

I read a topic right here on the Stack where the function was suggested:

```
dfRaw.applymap(lambda x: x if not isinstance(x, list) else x[0] if len(x) else '')
```

but this function for me is not interesting because it is efficient when the list has only one element. In my case each cell has a different size list.

Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
dfRaw['MESSAGES'] = dfRaw['MESSAGES'].str.join(', ')

  CLASS                      MESSAGES
0     1              mama, said, home
1     2    dad, said, soccer, reality
2     3                   matrix, you
3     1                run, neo, free
4     2                   what, doing
5     3             begnning, believe
6     2  choice, let, you, free, mind
```